# How to connect neo4j DB with drupal 7?

Tags: plugins, drupal-7, neo4j, graph-databases, solution

We have a problem with connecting Neo4j DB to Drupal 7, is there anyone have a solution or plug-in for it? 
Requirements for plug-in or solution is:

1. Match of skills (Nodes)
2. Recommendation engine / system
3. Fast response time
4. Possible to change / add the plug-in
5. Create users
6. Use it at AWS or rackspace

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing project for Drupal here : https://www.drupal.org/project/neo4j_connector

I never tested it but I know it exist.

BTW you can easy plug in by making http requests to the neo4j rest api, there are some php http clients available on github :

https://github.com/neoxygen/kwark

https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp

Comment: When i install the neo4j_connector, then i got this error message. is it something you have seen or worked with? 
-----------
Warning: require_once(/customers/4/d/8/beernominate.me/httpd.www/drupal-7.31/sites/all/modules/neo4j_connector/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in require_once() (line 7 of /customers/4/d/8/beernominate.me/httpd.www/drupal-7.31/sites/all/modules/neo4j_connector/neo4j_connector.module).

Comment: It seems like composer autoloader does not exist, did you ran the complete setup for the module and specifically installed vendors with composer ?

With Composer install the PHP Driver. Follow the instructions.

    cd PATH_TO_MODULE/
    composer install (or php composer.phar install)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean? what is php driver? i am novice in drupal, do you have guide step by step?